# Monte Carlo integration of exp(-x^2/2) from x=-infinity to x=+infinity

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, montecarlo, numerical-integration

I want to integrate

f(x) = exp(-x^2/2)

from x=-infinity to x=+infinity

by using the Monte Carlo method. I use the function `randn()` to generate all x_i for the function f(x_i) = exp(-x_i^2/2) I want to integrate to calculate afterwards the mean value of f([x_1,..x_n]). My problem is, that the result depends on what values I choose for my borders x1 and x2 (see below). My result is going far away from the real value by increasing the value of x1 and x2. Actually the result should be better and better by increasing x1 and x2.

Does someone see my mistake?

Here is my Matlab code

```
clear all;
b=10;                 % border
x1 = -b;              % left border
x2 = b;               % right border
n = 10^6;             % number of random numbers
x = randn(n,1);
f = ones(n,1);
g = exp(-(x.^2)/2); 
F = ((x2-x1)/n)*f'*g;
```

The right value should be ~2.5066.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want a normal distribution? In that context I would expect a uniform distribution.

Comment: @Daniel : I know that it works with a uniform distribution. But a wanted to do it with a normal distribution in order to get a better result.

Comment: Hint: try plotting your function along with the PDF of the normal distribution (from which your `x` are drawn using `randn`). You'll see that the normal PDF is always under your function. If you really want to use `randn` instead of `rand` you'll need to do a simple transformation so the the sampling function is always >= than your function (you'll also need to be able to calculate the area from which you're sampling).

Comment: @Samuel: If you really want to use a normal distribution, your approach is really unclear to me. How do you expect the samples of a normal distribution to be within a certain interval? There is something missing, in your current approach the expected value of `F` is not the integral you are trying to calculate.

Comment: @Daniel: I know that there is a huge error in my code. But I just do not see how I can solve that.

Comment: @Samuel: My problem is, I don't understand what you are tying to implement. I don't know any method starting with normal distributed samples and ending up with the integral. It's more a math question and not a programming question.

Comment: @Daniel, look at what I wrote

Comment: The errors in this code:  (1)  x's need to be sorted after randomizing them for integration to work. (2) This integration routine only works on x's with a uniformly distributed spacing. Because the x's are randomized in Monte Carlo, the spacing is also randomized.  An integration technique which can deal with random spacing is needed.

Comment: Also (3) this code randomizes between 0 and 1.  For Monte Carlo you want to randomize between your bounds.

Comment: @Samuel Out of curiosity, why Monte Carlo over straight numerical integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
clear all;
b=10;                 % border
x1 = -b;              % left border
x2 = b;               % right border
n = 10^6;             % number of random numbers

x = sort(abs(x1 - x2) * rand(n,1) + x1);
f = exp(-x.^2/2);
F = trapz(x,f)

F =

    2.5066
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets start with writing of general case of MC integration:

```
I = S f(x) * p(x) dx, x in [a...b]
```

`S` here is integral sign.

Usually, `p(x)` is normalized probability density function, `f(x)` you want to integrate, and algorithm is very simple one:

- set accumulator `s` to zero
- start loop of `N` events
- sample `x` randomly from `p(x)`
- given `x`, compute `f(x)` and add to accumulator
- back to start loop if not done
- if done, divide accumulator by `N` and return it

In simplest textbook case you have

```
I = S f(x) dx, x in [a...b]
```

where it means PDF is equal to uniformly distributed one

```
p(x) = 1/(b-a)
```

but what you have to sum is actually `(b-a)*f(x)`, because your integral now looks like

```
I = S (b-a)*f(x) 1/(b-a) dx, x in [a...b]
```

In general, if both `f(x)` and `p(x)` could serve as PDF, then it is matter of choice whether you integrate `f(x)` over `p(x)`, or `p(x)` over `f(x)`. No difference! (Well, except maybe computation time)

So, back to particular integral (which is equal to `\sqrt{2\pi}`, i believe)

```
I = S exp(-x^2/2) dx, x in [-infinity...infinity]
```

You could use more traditional approach like @Agriculturist and write it

```
I = S exp(-x^2/2)*(2a) 1/(2a) dx, x in [-a...a]
```

and sample `x` from U(0,1) in [-a...a] interval, and for each `x` compute exp() and average it and get the result

From what I understand, you want to use `exp()` as PDF, so your integral looks like

```
I = S D * exp(-x^2/2)/D dx, x in [-infinity...infinity]
```

PDF to be normalized so it shall include normalization factor `D`, which is exactly equal to `\sqrt{2 \pi}` from gaussian integral.

Now `f(x)` is just a constant equal to `D`. It doesn't depend on `x`. It means that you for each sampled `x` should add to accumulator a CONSTANT value of `D`. After running `N` samples, 
in accumulator you'll have exactly `N*D`. To find mean you'll divide by `N` and as a result you'll get perfect `D`, which is `\sqrt{2 \pi}`, which, in turn, is
2.5066.

Too rusty to write any matlab, and Happy New Year anyway

Comment: Using accumulators and loops is very time consuming in terms of both programming time and processing time.  Such an approach would be appropriate for procedural based programming language; however, this would be considered poor programming practice in a language like MATLAB.

Comment: @Agriculturist ?!? I didn't write a single line of code, loop or no loop

Comment: Upon closer inspection this solution has another issue.  If random x's are used then the spacing is non-uniform.  Non-uniform spacing screws up both the approach you suggest and the approach Samuel is using.  Check the 2D variant of the [trapz](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) command.  I removed the line from this solution which inaccurately described the solution I wrote so as not to create confusion.

Comment: Also, In your algorithm the execution of the function is the event. If the spacing is made uniform then this ceases being a Monte Carlo analysis and becomes straight numerical integration.  Bounds are necessary in Monte Carlo Analysis.

Comment: @Agriculturist There is nothing wrong with non-uniform spacing and/or non-uniform distribution. It is quite *natural* to use non-uniform distribution.

Comment: @Agriculturist `Bounds are necessary in Monte Carlo Analysis.` Huh?! There are a lot of unbound (one way, or two way) distribution used in Monte Carlo. Simple exercise in the spirit of what I wrote. Let's integrate exp(-x)*exp(-x^2/2) from 0 to Infinity. 1. Sample from uniform distribution but in finite interval, compute and accumulate both exponents, and with growing interval you'll get the answer. 2. Use exp(-x) as PDF, sample from exponential and compute exp(-x^2). 3. Use gaussian as PDF, sample normaly distributed numbers and accumulate exp(-x). Trust me, all three will make same outcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99742/discussion-between-agriculturist-and-severin-pappadeux).